# Android Volly Client Error while POST

Tags: php, android, post

I want to show upload percentage on a donutProgress bar. I have 2 class for this. One where all the thing done with the image file to be uploaded and the 2nd class which I extends AsyncTask in order to show the progress.

Now on the 2nd class I tried to post to my app server with Volly but it seems that the POST is not sending any data at all. I've checked all the parameter contains all the required value but I still getting the com.android.volly.ClientError; in the github documentation it says that it cause by the Network with 4xx error but by php page not receiving any post data.

Here is the entire code.

```
package com.mymss.mymss;
import static com.mymss.mymss.MarksFilter.changeBackArrowColor;

public class CaptureImage extends AppCompatActivity{

    Spinner s1,s2,s3;
    Button button;
    Boolean flag;
    ImageButton capture,upload,next,previous;
    ImageView imageContainer;
    TextView studentInfo;
    Toolbar toolbar;
    private static String StudentId,imgStr,sCode,defaultSession;
    DonutProgress donutProgress;
    String[] clas,sec,roll,cid,sid,rid,stdid,resultSet,rSetId;
    String url="",getSecUrl,getRollUrl,sID,sName,sMob,resultClass,resultSec,resultRoll,getStdUrl;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    JSONObject jsonObject;
    JSONArray jsonArray;
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter,aD2,aD3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_capture_image);
        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        defaultSession="2018";
        flag = false;
        s1 = findViewById(R.id.spClass);
        s2 = findViewById(R.id.spSec);
        s3 = findViewById(R.id.spRoll);
        button = findViewById(R.id.btnCaptureGet);
        imageContainer = findViewById(R.id.ImageView_image);
        previous = findViewById(R.id.leftBtn2);
        next = findViewById(R.id.rightBtn2);
        capture = findViewById(R.id.captureImage);
        donutProgress = findViewById(R.id.donut_progress1);
        upload = findViewById(R.id.upload);
        studentInfo = findViewById(R.id.imageName);
        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbarImage);
        imageContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        previous.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        next.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        studentInfo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        capture.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        upload.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        final UploadFileToServer uploadFileToServer;
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(changeBackArrowColor(this, Color.rgb(2, 2, 250)));
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        onBackPressed();

                    }
                }
        );

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        try {
            sID = intent.getExtras().getString("ID");
            sCode = intent.getExtras().getString("School");
            sName = intent.getExtras().getString("Name");
            sMob = intent.getExtras().getString("Mobile");

        }
        catch (NullPointerException e)
        {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(CaptureImage.this)
                    .setTitle("ERROR !!")
                    .setMessage("Error Code = "+e.toString())
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_logo)
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                            //finishAffinity();
                            //System.exit(0);
                        }
                    }).show();
        }
        url = "https://www.mymss.com/Android/photo.php?action=getclass&session="+defaultSession+"&code="+sCode+"&user="+sID;
        callNet(url,"Class");
        s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(
                new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                        try {

                            Object item = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);
                            if (item != null) {

                                //Toast.makeText(TeacherLand.this, item.toString() + " selected with mobile no "+number[i],
                                //      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                resultClass = cid[i];
                                //examName = exam[i];
                                if(resultClass.compareToIgnoreCase("0")!=0)
                                {
                                    getSecUrl = "https://www.mymss.com/Android/photo.php?action=secexam&session="+defaultSession+"&code="+sCode+"&user="+sID+"&element_1="+resultClass;
                                    callNet(getSecUrl,"Section");
                                }

                            }
                        }
                        catch (NullPointerException e)
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(CaptureImage.this,"Error Block",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

                    }
                }
        );
        s2.setOnItemSelectedListener(
                new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                        try {

                            Object item = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);
                            if (item != null) {

                                //Toast.makeText(TeacherLand.this, item.toString() + " selected with mobile no "+number[i],
                                //      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                resultSec = sid[i];
                                //examName = exam[i];
                                if(resultSec.compareToIgnoreCase("0")!=0)
                                {
                                    getRollUrl = "https://www.mymss.com/Android/photo.php?action=allroll&session="+defaultSession+"&code="+sCode+"&user="+sID+"&class="+resultClass+"&sec="+resultSec;
                                    callNet(getRollUrl,"Roll");
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        catch (NullPointerException e)
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(CaptureImage.this,"Error Block",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

                    }
                }
        );
        s3.setOnItemSelectedListener(
                new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                        try {

                            Object item = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);
                            if (item != null) {

                                //Toast.makeText(TeacherLand.this, item.toString() + " selected with mobile no "+number[i],
                                //      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                resultRoll = rid[i];
                                StudentId = stdid[i];

                                //examName = exam[i];
                                if(resultRoll.compareToIgnoreCase("0")!=0)
                                {
                                    getStdUrl = "https://www.mymss.com/Android/photo.php?action=get&session="+defaultSession+"&code="+sCode+"&user="+sID+"&stdid="+stdid[i];
                                    //callNet(getRollUrl,"Roll");
                                    button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        catch (NullPointerException e)
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(CaptureImage.this,"Error Block",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

                    }
                }
        );
        button.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        callNet(getStdUrl,"get");
                        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),getStdUrl,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
        );
        capture.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        CropImage.activity()
                                .setActivityTitle("ImageCrop")
                                .setAspectRatio(1,1)
                                .setMultiTouchEnabled(true)
                                .start(CaptureImage.this);
                    }
                }
        );
        uploadFileToServer = new UploadFileToServer(this,imgStr,sCode,defaultSession,StudentId);
        upload.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {


                        uploadFileToServer.execute();
                        //new UploadFileToServer().execute();
                        //uploadImage("blank",imgStr);
                    }
                }
        );

    }

    public static String getImgStr()
    {
        return imgStr;
    }
    public static String getsCode()
    {
        return sCode;
    }
    public static String getDefaultSession()
    {
        return defaultSession;
    }
    public static String getStudentId()
    {
        return StudentId;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE)
        {
            CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
            if(requestCode == 203 || requestCode == RESULT_OK)
            {
                Uri resultUri = result.getUri();
                imageContainer.setImageURI(resultUri);
                Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imageContainer.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                imgStr = imageConvert(bitmap);
                upload.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            else if(requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE)
            {

                Exception error = result.getError();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+error,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

    }

    public static Drawable changeBackArrowColor(Context context, int color) {
        String resName;
        int res;

        resName = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 ? "abc_ic_ab_back_material" : "abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha";
        res = context.getResources().getIdentifier(resName, "drawable", context.getPackageName());

        final Drawable upArrow = context.getResources().getDrawable(res);
        upArrow.setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);

        return upArrow;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.mymenu,menu);

        MenuItem menuItem1 = menu.findItem(R.id.sessionCurrent);
        MenuItem menuItem2 = menu.findItem(R.id.sessionNext);

        if(!menuItem1.isChecked() && !menuItem2.isChecked())
        {
            menuItem1.setChecked(true);
            defaultSession = menuItem1.getTitle().toString();
        }


        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch(item.getItemId())
        {
            case R.id.sessionCurrent:
                item.setChecked(true);
                defaultSession = item.getTitle().toString();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Session changed to "+item.getTitle().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.sessionNext:
                item.setChecked(true);
                defaultSession = item.getTitle().toString();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Session changed to "+item.getTitle().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }

        return true;
    }

    private String imageConvert(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,90,byteArrayOutputStream);
        byte[] imgBytes = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();


        return Base64.encodeToString(imgBytes,Base64.DEFAULT);
    }

    public void fillPic(String url)
    {

        View parentLayout = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        Snackbar.make(parentLayout,"Please Wait, Still Loading....... ",Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("CLOSE", new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                    }
                }).show();

        Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
                .load(url)
                .error(R.drawable.question)
                .fit()
                .into(imageContainer, new Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError() {

                        View parentLayout = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
                        Snackbar.make(parentLayout,"Image not available. ",Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .setAction("CLOSE", new View.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(View view) {

                                    }
                                }).show();
                    }
                });

    }

}

class UploadFileToServer extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    CaptureImage captureImage = new CaptureImage();
    DonutProgress donutProgress;
    ImageButton upload;
    public Activity activity;
    String image,code,session,StudentId;
    public UploadFileToServer(Activity _activity,String image,String code,String session,String StudentId)
    {

        this.activity = _activity;
        this.image = image;
        this.code = code;
        this.session = session;
        this.StudentId = StudentId;
        donutProgress = this.activity.findViewById(R.id.donut_progress1);
        upload = this.activity.findViewById(R.id.upload);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // setting progress bar to zero

        image = CaptureImage.getImgStr();
        code = CaptureImage.getsCode();
        session = CaptureImage.getDefaultSession();
        StudentId = CaptureImage.getStudentId();
        upload.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        donutProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
        //Log.d("PROG", progress[0]);
        //donut_progress.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0])); //Updating progress
        donutProgress.setProgress(Float.valueOf(progress[0]));
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(activity);
            StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,"https://www.mymss.com/Android/photo.php", new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    if (response.compareToIgnoreCase("success")==0) {
                        activity.runOnUiThread(
                                new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {

                                        //Toast.makeText(activity,"Code = "+code+" , Img = "+image+", Session = "+session,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        Toast.makeText(activity, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                }
                        );

                    }
                        else {
                        activity.runOnUiThread(
                                new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {

                                        //Toast.makeText(activity,"Code = "+code+" , Img = "+image+", Session = "+session,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        Toast.makeText(activity, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                }
                        );

                    }
                    donutProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    upload.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {


                    new AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
                            .setTitle("Error")
                            .setMessage("Invalid Response From Server.[Code = "+error.toString()+"]")
                            .setCancelable(false)
                            .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_logo)
                            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    dialog.cancel();
                                    //finishAffinity();
                                    //System.exit(0);
                                }
                            }).show();
                    donutProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }){
                @Override
                protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
                    Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    params.put("image",image);
                    params.put("code",code);
                    params.put("session",session);
                    params.put("addphoto", StudentId);

                    return params;
                }

                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    params.put("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                    return params;
                }
            };
            queue.add(sr);



        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        //Log.e("Response", "Response from server: " + result);
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

}
```

And here is the php code

```
<?php
file_put_contents('test.txt', $_POST);
if(isset($_POST['addphoto']))
{
$dir = $_POST['code'];
$session = $_POST['session'];
}
else{
$user = $_GET['user'];
$dir = $_GET['code'];
$session = $_GET['session'];
}

    $upOne = realpath(__DIR__ . '/..');

    $conn1=odbc_connect("DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};Dbq=$dbName","user","pass");        


if(isset($_POST['addphoto'])){
    $_POST['addphoto']=intval($_POST['addphoto']);
    if($_POST['addphoto']){
    $img = $_POST['image'];
$img = str_replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,', '', $img);
$img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
$data = base64_decode($img);
$time=time();
$filename=$time.'_'.$_POST['addphoto'].'.jpg';
$file = 'uploads/studentphoto/'.$filename;
$success = file_put_contents($file, $data);
$sql="select StudentId,img from StudentMain where StudentId=".$_POST['addphoto'];
$rs=odbc_exec($conn1,$sql)or die (print odbc_errormsg());
$row=odbc_fetch_array($rs);
if(file_exists("uploads/studentphoto/".$row['img']) && $row['img'])
unlink("uploads/studentphoto/".$row['img']);
$sql = "update StudentMain set img='".$filename."' where StudentId=".$row['StudentId'];
$rs = odbc_exec($conn1,$sql)or die (print odbc_errormsg());
echo 'success';




    }
}
?>
```

This is the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: does this is certificate issue? `https`

Comment: It looks like you have some serious SQL injection security flaws to fix in this - do not go live with them if you value your data or your users' security.

Comment: @halfer No probs mate I change the actual url.

Comment: any verbose logcat when volley requesting?

Comment: @DebasisMandal: changing the URL is not going to help you when you go live. You need to look into parameter binding as a matter of some urgency.

Answer (score 1):

In 'UploadFileToServer' you define:

```
CaptureImage captureImage = new CaptureImage();
```

And then use:

```
image = CaptureImage.getImgStr();
```

In

```
protected void onPreExecute() {
```

Without ever having assinged a new value to the image string, I would assume this is still null at the time. Instead, it seems like you want to pass *this* through to the constructor.

Comment: I Toast the image it displays lot of text, that seems it not null at the time of sending,    and yes the constructor didn't work that's why I initializing onPreExecute()

Answer (score 0):

It's finally working after removing the getHeaders() method from Volly. Don't know why but now it's working smoothly.